# Where to find code Snippets for PHP?

Tags: php, frameworks, code-snippets, user-management

I am developing a new website for a very low budget client and instead of building from scratch I am looking for some wireframe which can provide me with some basic user management features, i.e. User registration, login, forgot password so that I can spend more time on the functionality of website. I will be providing facebook connect as well as alternate to login.

any idea where to find PHP code for same? I have no issues in giving attribution or credit to the original developer so GNU license would be preferable.

I do not want to use any complex framework like Zend or Cakephp. All I am looking for are standalone PHP scripts.

Comment: You're looking for a content management system (CMS). I'm not sure if this is a programming question... you're asking about packaged software to use, but not any programming issues. One of the other SE sites may have more expertise for this such as webapps, webmasters, maybe even programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I think this question should posted somewhere else. Regarding your question, I think you can search in http://www.phpclasses.org/. There are lots of "ready to go classes" which can perform your required task.

Answer (score 1):

Why even tag this post with "frameworks" if you're specifically looking for something that's not a framework?

That aside, if you *were* looking for a light-weight framework, I'd go with CodeIgniter.